# How to build Ansible Playbook without username/password

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new to Ansible and started learning and working on Ansible Playboks especially on network automation. Part of our hosting infra, inorder to login to any device we have default script runs to ssh into the device, something like goto . Hence no need to give any username and password, it directly logs into the device. 
How we can include this customization in Ansible playbook without using any username or password.

Comment: Please provide examples and code

Answer (score 0):

Ansible supports using ssh keys.

> Confirm that you can connect using SSH to all the nodes in your inventory using the same username. If necessary, add your public SSH key to the authorized_keys file on those systems.

Refer to documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#action-check-your-ssh-connections)

Also, it is a good idea to read the 'getting started' [page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to supply a Username, that the SSH Key belongs to:

Guide on Setting up an SSH key for a Linux User: [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/)

Once SSH Key is configured and Copied over to your Ansible Server: 
Edit the Sudoers File on the Slave Node and set NOPASSWD for the user, that way your user won't be prompted for a password when you are duing Sudo Commands: [Reference Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/)